# How to denote that an expression is expressed in a given language

Tags: logic

I want to say something like "Given an expression *E* in language *L*..."

Is there a 'standard' symbol for '*expressed in*'?

I think that 'Given expression *E* ∈ *L*' is not accurate, as a language is not defined merely as the set of all valid expressions.

Comment: A language *is* defined as the set of syntactically valid expressions. (Sometimes with a distinction between different types of expressions such as term or formula.)

Comment: syntax + semantics

Comment: In topology, we say "Given a point $x\in X$", even though a topological space isn't just a set of points. In algebra, we say "Given an element $a\in A$", even though neither groups nor rings (not any other algebraic structure) are merely sets of elements. I don't know about the conventions in your field, but it's common enough elsewhere.

Comment: @Lior Kogan No. A formal language is a purely syntactic concept. The semantics only enters through models/interpretations (which are of course defined relative to the language).

Comment: @lemontree. I see. I would accept this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A language *is* defined as the set of syntactically valid expressions. Most of the time a distinction is made between different types of expressions such as "term" or "formula"; in predicate logic, "language" in the narrower sense usually refers to the set of formulas in the language. You fill find definitions such as "If $P$ is an $n$-ary predicate symbol and $t_1, ..., t_n$ are terms, then $P(t_1, ..., t_n)$ is a well-formed formula of $\mathcal{L}$", or "If $\phi, \psi \in \mathcal{L}$, then $\phi \to \psi \in \mathcal{L}$". So you inductively define a set whose elements are expressions of that language, and then at the end of the definition often make a disclaimer along the lines of "Nothing else is in $\mathcal{L}$", meaning that the resulting set indeed consists of nothing else but these expressions.

The semantics only enters through models/interpretations. Of course, these are defined relative to a given language, but a formal language itself a purely syntactic concept - a set of syntactically valid strings of symbols from the alphabet of the language.

So the answer to your question is: "Given $e \in \mathcal{L}$" is perfectly fine (though by convention you'd probably choose a different symbol than $e$, possibly $\phi$ or $t$ or something depending on what type of expression $e$ is supposed to denote).